# Enforce DML statement to be failed within a batch

Tags: batch, code-coverage, dml, adderror

I am trying to make a DML statement in a batch to be failed.
The reason for this is that I have logic executed in my batch in case the DML failed for some records. I would like to test it and get the code covered.

I.e. When I perform

```
Case c = new Case(.....);
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
cases.add(c);
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
    c.addError('Custom Error');
}

Database.DeleteResult[] srs = Database.delete(cases,false);
```

What I get is that this DML always succeed. There DeleteResult isSuccess method always return true even if I call the addError method.

Please advise.
Thanks.